# Java getNodeName and namespaces

Tags: java, xml

Given 2 XML files that conform to the same schema (both valid), one has namespaces, the other one has not (sample):

**XML File 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<message xmlns="http://www.somewhere.com/X">
    <messageheader>
    ...
</message>
```

**XML File 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:message xmlns:ns1="http://www.somewhere.com/X">
    <ns1:messageheader>
    ...
</ns1:message>
```

The issue is that the code that parses the file uses the Element.getNodeName() getter to determine node names before extracting and storing the text content.  This method was used as opposed to XPath when parsing the XML due to performance.

Therefore the following sample code was implemented to do the parsing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < someElement.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
    if(someElement.getChildNodes().item(i).getNodeType() == org.w3c.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element element = (Element) someElement.getChildNodes().item(i);

        if(element.getNodeName().equals("ns1:messageheader")) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The above code only works with XML File 2.

Is it possible to determine whether a file uses the namespace prefix on elements so both files can be parsed using getNodeName() - so I can use the same code to parse both files?

I agree this is an awful way to parse the XML.  Unfortunately, my code was implemented before switching to JAXB which I love (for the moment).

Thanks

Andez

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (element.getLocalName().equals("messageheader") &&
    "http://www.somewhere.com/X".equals(element.getNamespaceURI())) { ...
```

You have to check that the local name and the namespace match, regardless of the prefix.

Answer (score 10):

Use `getLocalName()` instead of `getNodeName()`. This will return the unqualified name of the element.

Comment: Something to note: If you parse this document with a non-namespace-aware API, getLocalName() will always return null. Make sure your DocumentBuilder is namespace-aware

Comment: Yes, thanks for that rmlan...  I'm thinking I looked at the getLocalName and it did return null before - that's why I went down the getNodeName route using the prefix. +1

Comment: Following @rmlan comment : `DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();` **factory.setNamespaceAware(true);**

Comment: @VincentBlouin This is not working for me. `getLocalName()` keeps returning `null` although `localName` isn't `null`.

Comment: @AlaaM. Quote from Javadoc: `For nodes of any type other than ELEMENT_NODE and ATTRIBUTE_NODE and nodes created with a DOM Level 1 method, such as Document.createElement(), this is always null.`