# W3C xml get element with namespace and without namespace

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, w3c

I have a XML like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
 <Entities xmlns="sample">
  <Entity>
    sample Value
   </Entity>
   <ns1:Entity xmlns:ns1="sample">
     sample Value
   </ns1:Entity>
 </Entities>
```

When I use `nodeElement.getNodeName();`, I can only able to get `<Entity>` not `<ns1:Entity>`.
I verified [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882433/java-getnodename-and-namespaces) and tried `getLocalName()` instead of `getNodeName()`. It is not working. Also when I tried using `getElementByTagNameNS("Entity","sample")`, the   `getLength()` method returned a 0.

**Updated:**

As mentioned in the below answer I interchanged the parameters of `getElementByTagNameNS`.
I see an option to use `getElementByTagNameNS("*","Entity")` which allows me not to hardcode the namespace in the code. Now wanted to know, is there any disadvantage of using `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementByTagNameNS("Entity","sample")` should be `getElementsByTagNameNS("sample","Entity")`, i.e. the namespace name comes before the local name.

You may have made a similar mistake when trying to get `nodeElement.getNodeName()` but you haven't posted the relevant code.

Comment: Hi. I see another option with getElementsByTagNameNS("*","Entity") which means Element Entity with any namespace. I dont want to hardcode the namespace in the code. I'm thinking of using *. Just want to know, is there any other disadvantage of using *.

Comment: Not that I know of. It seems a little odd, because elements with the sane local name but different namespaces aren't really related in any meaningful way; It's like getting all the elements that happen to be part of a co-incidence. So I wouldn't do it. But on a practical level, if it gets you the elements you want, fair enough.